# How to pass an external method to a stateless functional component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, flow-router

I am using FlowRouter/Meteor with React, and am trying to pass a FlowRouter.go method to a react button to navigate to a new page when the button is pressed. I want to do this to keep the button as a reusable component, but am struggling to figure out how to pass the FlowRouter.go method into the stateless functional component. This is a simplified version of what I have right now:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlowRouter } from 'meteor/kadira:flow-router';

const ParentComponent = () => {
  // define text and styles here
  return (
    <div>
      <Button text={text} style={styles} action={FlowRouter.go("Register")}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and then my button component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// Call to action button
const Button = ({text, style, action}) => {
  return (
    <button className="btn" style={style} onClick={() => action()}>
      {text}
    </button>
  );
}

Button.propTypes = {
  text: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  style: React.PropTypes.object,
  action: React.PropTypes.func
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  text: "A button.",
  style: {
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
  },
  action: null
};

export default Button
```

Does anyone know what syntax is required to load methods from third party libraries into React functional components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass in a function.  You are actually executing the `FlowRouter.go` function by calling `FlowRouter.go("Register")`.

Try this:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  // define text and styles here
  return (
    <div>
      <Button text={text} style={styles} action={() => FlowRouter.go("Register")}/>
   </div>
  );
}
```

Also... as `action` is a function you can pass it directly to your onClick, like so:

```
<button className="btn" style={style} onClick={action}>
```

Comment: You are my new favorite person. I figured it had to do with where/how the function was executing. Thank you!